# How to put raw data in a http get request in Flutter(Dart)?

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I'm trying to execute the following curl in dart but I can't find a way to achieve that:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://someurl.com/query' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
--data-raw '{
    "query":"test_value",
    "size":10
}'
```

The only way I've found to achieve this is to use POST and put the raw data inside the body but I was wondering if there is a real way to achieve that since the POST request with a body seems to be about 220ms slower than the GET one(I know that they should be almost equal, it may be something from the server when recieving the request).

Comment: What have you tried dart wise? It looks like you need to set some headers in your get request. Have you checked the http docs https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `get()` method of the `http` package doesn't allow you to add data since that isn't a common thing to do. You can get around this by using the `Request` object directly for more fine-grained control, [as stated in the docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html):

```dart
Request req = Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://someurl.com/query'))
  ..body = json.encode(data)
  ..headers.addAll({
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer xxxx"
  });

var response await req.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // do something with valid response
}
```

I'd look at getting the POST variant working properly, since a GET method semantically shouldn't do anything with the provided body. But that's a different discussion of course.

Comment: I completly missed the .addAll method from the headers map, thought that you couldn't modify the headers in the Request object, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// Define the raw data to be sent in the request
String rawData = '{ "key": "value" }';

// Send the GET request with the raw data as the body
http.Response response = await http.get(
  'https://example.com/endpoint',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: rawData,
);

// Check the status code of the response to see if the request was successful
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // The request was successful, process the response
} else {
  // The request was not successful, handle the error
}
```